# Z-Index Layering Issue (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm just learning/practicing, so any help would be SUPER appreciated. Also, if you find other errors or inefficiencies while looking, I'd love to hear about it.

I have four layers.

.body
.main
.main-side
.sidebar

[This](http://www.csszengarden.com/217/) is essentially what I'm trying to recreate , and everything is working fine other than the third layer, or in the case of the example, the navy blue bar extending vertical on the right side. I can get it to go to the second layer (right above the main background) or cover up everything (including the sidebar), but I can't get it between layer two and four (in the example, the light blue inner box and the smaller, yellow side box.) Thanks in advance!

Here is the HTML and the CSS.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
    <title>CSS Zen Garden</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-side"></div>
<div class="main">
    <h1 class="redbox">CSS Zen Garden</h1>

    <h2>The Beauty of CSS Design</h2>
    <div class="sub-heading">
        <p class="top>">A demonstration of what can be accomplished through CSS-based design. Select any style sheet from the list to load it into this page.</p>

        <hr>

        <p class="bottom">Download the example <a href="#">HTML file</a> and <a href="#">CSS file</a>
    </div>
<div class="enlightenment">         
    <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>

        <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible DOMs, broken CSS support, and abandoned browsers</p>

        <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the W3C, WaSP, and the major browser creators.</p>

        <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
</div>

<div class="about">
    <h3>So What is This About?</h3>

        <p>There is a continuing need to show the power of CSS. The Zen Garden aims to excite, inspire, and encourage participation. To begin, view some of the existing designs in the list. Clicking on any one will load the style sheet into this very page. The HTML remains the same, the only thing that has changed is the external CSS file. Yes, really.</p>

        <p>CSS allows complete and total control over the style of a hypertext document. The only way this can be illustrated in a way that gets people excited is by demonstrating what it can truly be, once the reins are placed in the hands of those able to create beauty from structure. Designers and coders alike have contributed to the beauty of the web; we can always push it further.</p>
</div>

<div class="participation">
    <h3>Participation</h3>

        <p>Strong visual design has always been our focus. You are modifying this page, so strong CSS skills are necessary too, but the example files are commented well enough that even CSS novices can use them as starting points. Please see the CSS Resource Guide for advanced tutorials and tips on working with CSS.</p>

        <p>You may modify the style sheet in any way you wish, but not the HTML. This may seem daunting at first if you’ve never worked this way before, but follow the listed links to learn more, and use the sample files as a guide.</p>

        <p>Download the sample HTML and CSS to work on a copy locally. Once you have completed your masterpiece (and please, don’t submit half-finished work) upload your CSS file to a web server under your control. Send us a link to an archive of that file and all associated assets, and if we choose to use it we will download it and place it on our server.</p>
</div>

<div class="benefits">
    <h3>Benefits</h3>

        <p>Why participate? For recognition, inspiration, and a resource we can all refer to showing people how amazing CSS really can be. This site serves as equal parts inspiration for those working on the web today, learning tool for those who will be tomorrow, and gallery of future techniques we can all look forward to.</p>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Select a Design:</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a> by                       <a href="http://andrewlohman.com/" class="designer-name">Andrew Lohman</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/220/" class="design-name">Garments</a> by                     <a href="http://danielmall.com/" class="designer-name">Dan Mall</a>
            </li>                   

            <li>
                <a href="/219/" class="design-name">Steel</a> by                        <a href="http://steffen-knoeller.de" class="designer-name">Steffen Knoeller</a>
            </li>                   

            <li>
                <a href="/218/" class="design-name">Apothecary</a> by                       <a href="http://trentwalton.com" class="designer-name">Trent Walton</a>
            </li>                   

            <li>
                <a href="/217/" class="design-name">Screen Filler</a> by                        <a href="http://elliotjaystocks.com/" class="designer-name">Elliot Jay Stocks</a>
            </li>                   

            <li>
                <a href="/216/" class="design-name">Fountain Kiss</a> by                        <a href="http://jeremycarlson.com" class="designer-name">Jeremy Carlson</a>
            </li>                   

            <li>
                <a href="/215/" class="design-name">A Robot Named Jimmy</a> by                      <a href="http://meltmedia.com/" class="designer-name">meltmedia</a>
            </li>                   

            <li>
                <a href="/214/" class="design-name">Verde Moderna</a> by                        <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/" class="designer-name">Dave Shea</a>
            </li>                   
        </ul>

    <h3>Archives:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/217/page1">                   Next Designs <span class="indicator">&rsaquo;</span></a>
                </li>

            <li>
            <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/alldesigns/" title="View every submission to the Zen Garden.">View All Designs</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    <h3>Resources:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/217/217.css" title="View the source CSS file of the currently-viewed design.">View This Design&#8217;s CSS</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/resources/" title="Links to great sites with information on using CSS.">CSS Resources</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/faq/" title="A list of Frequently Asked Questions about the Zen Garden.">FAQ</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/submit/" title="Send in your own CSS file.">
                Submit a Design</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/translations/" title="View translated versions of this page.">Translations</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="requirements">
    <h3>Requirements</h3>

        <p>Where possible, we would like to see mostly CSS 1 & 2 usage. CSS 3 & 4 should be limited to widely-supported elements only, or strong fallbacks should be provided. The CSS Zen Garden is about functional, practical CSS and not the latest bleeding-edge tricks viewable by 2% of the browsing public. The only real requirement we have is that your CSS validates.</p>

        <p>Luckily, designing this way shows how well various browsers have implemented CSS by now. When sticking to the guidelines you should see fairly consistent results across most modern browsers. Due to the sheer number of user agents on the web these days — especially when you factor in mobile — pixel-perfect layouts may not be possible across every platform. That’s okay, but do test in as many as you can. Your design should work in at least IE9+ and the latest Chrome, Firefox, iOS and Android browsers (run by over 90% of the population).</p>

        <p>We ask that you submit original artwork. Please respect copyright laws. Please keep objectionable material to a minimum, and try to incorporate unique and interesting visual themes to your work. We’re well past the point of needing another garden-related design.</p>

        <p>This is a learning exercise as well as a demonstration. You retain full copyright on your graphics (with limited exceptions, see submission guidelines), but we ask you release your CSS under a Creative Commons license identical to the one on this site so that others may learn from your work.</p>

        <hr>
    <div class="author">
        <p>By <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/">Dave Shea</a>. Bandwidth graciously donated by <a href="http://www.mediatemple.net/">mediatemple</a>. Now available: <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321303474">Zen Garden, the book</a>.</p>
    </author>
</div>

        <footer>
            <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer" title="Check the validity of this site&#8217;s HTML" class="zen-validate-html">HTML</a>
            <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" title="Check the validity of this site&#8217;s CSS" class="zen-validate-css">CSS</a>
            <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/" title="View the Creative Commons license of this site: Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike." class="zen-license">CC</a>
            <a href="http://mezzoblue.com/zengarden/faq/#aaa" title="Read about the accessibility of this site" class="zen-accessibility">A11y</a>
            <a href="https://github.com/mezzoblue/csszengarden.com" title="Fork this site on Github" class="zen-github">GH</a>
        </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>


body    {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    line-height: 120%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    background: #daede2;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 90%;
    vertical-align: center;
}

p   {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

h1  {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}

h2  {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 130px;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: -.025em;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-heading    {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 0 50px 14px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: .07em;
    font-size: 18px;
}

h3  {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.main   {
    background: #77c4d3;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 5000px;
}

.main-side  {
    background: #3a4453;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1020px;
    height: 2000px;
    top: -200px;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.redbox {
    background: #df3c56;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 224px;
    text-align: center;
}

.enlightenment  {
    background: #f2f9fb;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 0;
    width: 58%;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.about  {
    color: white;
    width: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 250px;
}

.about h3 {
    color: white;
}

.benefits   {
    background: #f2f9fb;
    position: relative;
    top: 225px;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    left: 50px;
}

.sidebar    {
    background: #e9f198;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 200%;
    letter-spacing: -.01em;
    padding-right: 40px;
    z-index: 4;
}

.sidebar a, h3  {
    color: #333;
}

.sidebar h3 {
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.participation  {
    background: #df3c56;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -618px;
    right: 80px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.participation p {
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

.participation h3 {
    color: white;
}

.requirements   {
    background: #f2f9fb;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -625px;
    width: 57%;
    padding: 50px;
}

.requirements a {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.author {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer  {
    background: #e9f198;
    position: relative;
    top: 119px;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 22px;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    color: #333;
    left: -440px;
    width: 80%;
}

a   {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

hr  {
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #df3c56;
    width: 93%;
    margin: 50px 0 50px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is move `.main-side` into `.main` so you can add the right `z-index` to it to make it overlap like the example you posted and adjust the values:

```
.main-side  {
  background: rgba(58,68,83, .8); //convert to rgba so you can fade the background like the example
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px; //update - change to right instead
  height: 2400px; //update
  top: -200px;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I also converted some of your colors to `rgba` to give it that transparent look.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qcy12na/2/)

Comment: Awesome. That worked completely. Now, I if I could trouble you once more, could you answer why that worked and mine didn't? Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm still very new to CSS. This was the first CSS I had ever written myself and beside it being (probably) not overly efficient, and this not working, I was pretty proud of it.

Comment: you should be proud, it's a good start. working with `z-index` helps to layer things but you wanted to slide `main-side` in between two elements that were contained inside the same area. So `main-slide` just needed to be in there too. You could have had `main-slide` behind both elements or on top of both but not in between. Hope that makes sense and good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but here's a few things that might help. First, to achieve what they are with the yellow menu, you should use something like this:

```
.sidebar    {
    background: #e9f198;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: -100px;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 200%;
    letter-spacing: -.01em;
    padding-right: 40px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

You'll see that the sidebar is now placed more like theirs.

And with these two changes, does it get closer to what you're looking for?

```
.main   {
    background: #77c4d3;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 5000px;
}

.main-side  {
    background: #3a4453;
    position: absolute;
    left: 900px;
    height: 2000px;
    top: 70px;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I've also made a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cd2vLh1w/), which you should always do in the future for questions like this!

Comment: Thanks Jamie. The first part definitely made more sense than my use of CSS, and is quite a bit more efficient. I couldn't get the second portion to work, but it appears that the comment below this one answered it. I have to move the .main-sidebar inside the .main (in the HTML) part. That fixed it. Thanks again!